# How to run `bun install` in a different directory than the current?

Tags: bun

For instance, say I'm in the parent folder of `app` folder where `package.json` is, and I want to install dependencies for `app` without `cd` into it.

I tried:

```bash
bun --prefix app install # the npm way
```

```bash
bun --dir app install # the pnpm way
```

```bash
bun --cwd app install # the bun way, but only works with `run` scripts like `bun start`
```

None of the above worked. Is it supported at all?

Answer (score 1):

If the directory structure is `parent > app > package.json` and you are currently in `parent`, you can install all dependencies with this command:

```
bun install --cwd ./app
```

If you need to install a new dependency, for example `react`, you can use this command:

```
bun add react --cwd ./app
```

This command will also create a `package.json` file if not present.